# Can't get sails-hook-validate to work with Sails v1.0?

Tags: sails.js, sails-hook

I am having an issue getting validation error messages to attach to the error object in sails v1.0.  I am using the [sails-hook-validate](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-validation) module.

User model:

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

   name: {
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
   }

  },

  validationMessages: {
   name: {
    required: 'Name is required'
   },
  },

};
```

Running User.create in the sails console:

```
sails> User.create({}).exec(err => console.log(err.toJSON()));
{ error: 'E_UNKNOWN',
  status: 500,
  summary: 'Encountered an unexpected error',
  Errors: undefined }
```

It appears sails-hook-validate is modifying the error object in some way, but it doesn't seem to be adding my custom error message in any way.  Does anybody know how to get sails-hook-validate to work in Sails v1.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sails v1 dramatically changed how validation errors are formatted and **sails-hook-validate** hasn't been updated to handle Sails v1 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sails-hook-validate is a third party hook and I dont think its been updated to work with Sails V1.
As @jeffery mentioned the structure of validation errors did change slightly in Sails V1 but there could be other changes that are effecting this hook.